# Combine a list of data frames into one data frame by row

Tags: r, list, dataframe, r-faq

I have code that at one place ends up with a list of data frames which I really want to convert to a single big data frame.

I got some pointers from an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652522/rbind-dataframes-in-a-list-of-lists) which was trying to do something similar but more complex.

Here's an example of what I am starting with (this is grossly simplified for illustration):

```
listOfDataFrames <- vector(mode = "list", length = 100)

for (i in 1:100) {
    listOfDataFrames[[i]] <- data.frame(a=sample(letters, 500, rep=T),
                             b=rnorm(500), c=rnorm(500))
}
```

I am currently using this:

```
  df <- do.call("rbind", listOfDataFrames)
```

Comment: Also see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209258/merge-several-data-frames-into-one-data-frame-with-a-loop/2209371

Comment: The `do.call("rbind", list)` idiom is what I have used before as well.  Why do you need the initial `unlist` ?

Comment: can someone explain to me the difference between do.call("rbind", list) and rbind(list) - why are the outputs not the same?

Comment: @user6571411 Because do.call() does not return the arguments one by one, but uses a list to hold the arguments of the function. See [https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/Docall.html](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/Docall.html)

Answer (score 327, accepted):

Use `bind_rows()` from the **dplyr** package:

```
bind_rows(list_of_dataframes, .id = "column_label")
```

Comment: Nice solution. `.id = "column_label"` adds the unique row names based on the list element names.

Comment: since it's 2018 and `dplyr` is both fast and a solid tool to use, I've changed this to the accepted answer. The years, they fly by!

Comment: That was exactly what I needed!!

Comment: Strange but it does not work properly with list of tibbles

Answer (score 196):

One other option is to use a plyr function:

```
df <- ldply(listOfDataFrames, data.frame)
```

This is a little slower than the original:

```
> system.time({ df <- do.call("rbind", listOfDataFrames) })
   user  system elapsed 
   0.25    0.00    0.25 
> system.time({ df2 <- ldply(listOfDataFrames, data.frame) })
   user  system elapsed 
   0.30    0.00    0.29
> identical(df, df2)
[1] TRUE
```

My guess is that using `do.call("rbind", ...)` is going to be the fastest approach that you will find unless you can do something like (a) use a matrices instead of a data.frames and (b) preallocate the final matrix and assign to it rather than growing it.

*Edit 1*:

Based on Hadley's comment, here's the latest version of `rbind.fill` from CRAN:

```
> system.time({ df3 <- rbind.fill(listOfDataFrames) })
   user  system elapsed 
   0.24    0.00    0.23 
> identical(df, df3)
[1] TRUE
```

This is easier than rbind, and marginally faster (these timings hold up over multiple runs).  And as far as I understand it, [the version of `plyr` on github](http://github.com/hadley/plyr) is even faster than this.

Comment: rbind.fill in the latest version of plyr is considerably faster than do.call and rbind

Comment: interesting. for me rbind.fill was the fastest. Weird enough,  do.call / rbind did not return identical TRUE, even if i could ne find a difference. The other two were equal but plyr was slower.

Comment: `I()` could replace `data.frame` in your `ldply` call

Comment: there's also `melt.list` in reshape(2)

Comment: `do.call(function(...) rbind(..., make.row.names=F), df)` is useful if you don't want the automatically-generated unique rownames.

Comment: `bind_rows()` is fastest according to [rmd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38509685/3277050) and I think it is the most straight forward. It also has the feature of adding an [id column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49017065/3277050)

Answer (score 141):

For the purpose of completeness, I thought the answers to this question required an update. "My guess is that using `do.call("rbind", ...)` is going to be the fastest approach that you will find..." It was probably true for May 2010 and some time after, but in about Sep 2011 a new function `rbindlist` was introduced in the `data.table` package version 1.8.2, with a remark that "This does the same as `do.call("rbind",l)`, but much faster". How much faster?

```
library(rbenchmark)
benchmark(
  do.call = do.call("rbind", listOfDataFrames),
  plyr_rbind.fill = plyr::rbind.fill(listOfDataFrames), 
  plyr_ldply = plyr::ldply(listOfDataFrames, data.frame),
  data.table_rbindlist = as.data.frame(data.table::rbindlist(listOfDataFrames)),
  replications = 100, order = "relative", 
  columns=c('test','replications', 'elapsed','relative')
  )
```

---

```
                  test replications elapsed relative
4 data.table_rbindlist          100    0.11    1.000
1              do.call          100    9.39   85.364
2      plyr_rbind.fill          100   12.08  109.818
3           plyr_ldply          100   15.14  137.636
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this -- I was pulling my hair out because my data sets were getting too big for `ldply`ing a bunch of long, molten data frames. Anyways, I got an incredible speedup by using your `rbindlist` suggestion.

Comment: And one more for completeness: `dplyr::rbind_all(listOfDataFrames)` will do the trick as well.

Comment: is there an equivalent to `rbindlist` but that append the data frames by column ? something like a cbindlist ?

Comment: @rafa.pereira There is a recent feature request:
 [add function cbindlist](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2576)

Comment: I was also pulling my hair out because `do.call()` had been running on a list of data frames for 18 hours, and still hadn't finished, thank you!!!

Answer (score 119):

[image: bind-plot]

Code:

```
library(microbenchmark)

dflist <- vector(length=10,mode="list")
for(i in 1:100)
{
  dflist[[i]] <- data.frame(a=runif(n=260),b=runif(n=260),
                            c=rep(LETTERS,10),d=rep(LETTERS,10))
}


mb <- microbenchmark(
plyr::rbind.fill(dflist),
dplyr::bind_rows(dflist),
data.table::rbindlist(dflist),
plyr::ldply(dflist,data.frame),
do.call("rbind",dflist),
times=1000)

ggplot2::autoplot(mb)
```

Session:

```
R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

> packageVersion("plyr")
[1] ‘1.8.4’
> packageVersion("dplyr")
[1] ‘0.5.0’
> packageVersion("data.table")
[1] ‘1.9.6’
```

---

**UPDATE**:
Rerun 31-Jan-2018. Ran on the same computer. New versions of packages. Added seed for seed lovers.

[image]

```
set.seed(21)
library(microbenchmark)

dflist <- vector(length=10,mode="list")
for(i in 1:100)
{
  dflist[[i]] <- data.frame(a=runif(n=260),b=runif(n=260),
                            c=rep(LETTERS,10),d=rep(LETTERS,10))
}


mb <- microbenchmark(
  plyr::rbind.fill(dflist),
  dplyr::bind_rows(dflist),
  data.table::rbindlist(dflist),
  plyr::ldply(dflist,data.frame),
  do.call("rbind",dflist),
  times=1000)

ggplot2::autoplot(mb)+theme_bw()


R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

> packageVersion("plyr")
[1] ‘1.8.4’
> packageVersion("dplyr")
[1] ‘0.7.2’
> packageVersion("data.table")
[1] ‘1.10.4’
```

---

**UPDATE**: Rerun 06-Aug-2019.

[image]

```
set.seed(21)
library(microbenchmark)

dflist <- vector(length=10,mode="list")
for(i in 1:100)
{
  dflist[[i]] <- data.frame(a=runif(n=260),b=runif(n=260),
                            c=rep(LETTERS,10),d=rep(LETTERS,10))
}


mb <- microbenchmark(
  plyr::rbind.fill(dflist),
  dplyr::bind_rows(dflist),
  data.table::rbindlist(dflist),
  plyr::ldply(dflist,data.frame),
  do.call("rbind",dflist),
  purrr::map_df(dflist,dplyr::bind_rows),
  times=1000)

ggplot2::autoplot(mb)+theme_bw()

R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas/libblas.so.3
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenblasp-r0.2.20.so

packageVersion("plyr")
packageVersion("dplyr")
packageVersion("data.table")
packageVersion("purrr")

>> packageVersion("plyr")
[1] ‘1.8.4’
>> packageVersion("dplyr")
[1] ‘0.8.3’
>> packageVersion("data.table")
[1] ‘1.12.2’
>> packageVersion("purrr")
[1] ‘0.3.2’
```

---

**UPDATE**: Rerun 18-Nov-2021.

[image]

```
set.seed(21)
library(microbenchmark)

dflist <- vector(length=10,mode="list")
for(i in 1:100)
{
  dflist[[i]] <- data.frame(a=runif(n=260),b=runif(n=260),
                            c=rep(LETTERS,10),d=rep(LETTERS,10))
}


mb <- microbenchmark(
  plyr::rbind.fill(dflist),
  dplyr::bind_rows(dflist),
  data.table::rbindlist(dflist),
  plyr::ldply(dflist,data.frame),
  do.call("rbind",dflist),
  Reduce("rbind",dflist),
  purrr::map_df(dflist,dplyr::bind_rows),
  times=1000)

ggplot2::autoplot(mb)+theme_bw()

R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19043)

>packageVersion("plyr")
[1] ‘1.8.6’
> packageVersion("dplyr")
[1] ‘1.0.7’
> packageVersion("data.table")
[1] ‘1.14.2’
> packageVersion("purrr")
[1] ‘0.3.4’
```

---

**UPDATE**: Rerun 14-Dec-2023. Updated version of R and packages, but same machine. Also added Mael's answer with `collapse` package.

[image]

```
set.seed(21)
library(microbenchmark)

dflist <- vector(length=10,mode="list")
for(i in 1:100) dflist[[i]] <- data.frame(a=runif(n=260), b=runif(n=260), c=rep(LETTERS,10), d=rep(LETTERS,10))

mb <- microbenchmark(
  plyr::rbind.fill(dflist),
  dplyr::bind_rows(dflist),
  data.table::rbindlist(dflist),
  plyr::ldply(dflist,data.frame),
  do.call("rbind",dflist),
  Reduce("rbind",dflist),
  purrr::map_df(dflist,dplyr::bind_rows),
  collapse::unlist2d(dflist),
  times=1000)

ggplot2::autoplot(mb)+ggplot2::theme_bw()
```

```
Unit: microseconds
                                    expr     min       lq       mean   median       uq      max neval
                plyr::rbind.fill(dflist)  7146.5  7514.00  8270.0111  7753.80  8112.95  23541.9  1000
                dplyr::bind_rows(dflist)  1319.7  1476.35  1772.7105  1566.60  1668.40  13891.0  1000
           data.table::rbindlist(dflist)   466.8   603.20   828.2240   661.35   713.50  85147.2  1000
         plyr::ldply(dflist, data.frame) 14537.2 15161.20 16701.7973 15556.20 16417.50 101030.9  1000
                do.call("rbind", dflist)  9345.5  9851.10 12995.3883 10408.55 16046.65 110697.6  1000
                 Reduce("rbind", dflist) 71055.8 78980.90 97294.2492 83496.15 91894.60 285057.9  1000
 purrr::map_df(dflist, dplyr::bind_rows) 15097.9 15654.65 17361.9197 16020.10 16681.60 660603.4  1000
              collapse::unlist2d(dflist)   186.7   254.80   528.7272   312.90   351.90  88946.8  1000
```

```
R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)

> packageVersion("plyr")
[1] ‘1.8.9’
> packageVersion("dplyr")
[1] ‘1.1.4’
> packageVersion("data.table")
[1] ‘1.14.10’
> packageVersion("purrr")
[1] ‘1.0.2’
> packageVersion("collapse")
[1] ‘2.0.7’
> packageVersion("microbenchmark")
[1] ‘1.4.10’
```

Comment: This is a great answer.  I ran the same thing (same OS, same packages, different randomization because you don't `set.seed`) but saw some differences in worst-case performance.  `rbindlist` actually had the best worst-case as well as best typical-case in my results

Answer (score 51):

There is also `bind_rows(x, ...)` in `dplyr`.

```
> system.time({ df.Base <- do.call("rbind", listOfDataFrames) })
   user  system elapsed 
   0.08    0.00    0.07 
> 
> system.time({ df.dplyr <- as.data.frame(bind_rows(listOfDataFrames)) })
   user  system elapsed 
   0.01    0.00    0.02 
> 
> identical(df.Base, df.dplyr)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: technically speaking you do not need the as.data.frame - all that does it makes it exclusively a data.frame, as opposed to also a table_df (from deplyr)

Answer (score 23):

Here's another way this can be done (just adding it to the answers because `reduce` is a very effective functional tool that is often overlooked as a replacement for loops. In this particular case, neither of these are significantly faster than do.call)

using base R:

```
df <- Reduce(rbind, listOfDataFrames)
```

or, using the tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse) # or, library(dplyr); library(purrr)
df <- listOfDataFrames %>% reduce(bind_rows)
```

Comment: I always use base unless a package is really so much better. . .thanks for base solution

Answer (score 14):

How it should be done in the tidyverse:

```
df.dplyr.purrr <- listOfDataFrames %>% map_df(bind_rows)
```

Comment: Why would you use `map` if `bind_rows` can take a list of dataframes?

Comment: As of purrr 1.0.0 `*_df()` functions have been superseded.

Answer (score 12):

The only thing that the solutions with `data.table` are missing is the identifier column to know from which dataframe in the list the data is coming from.

Something like this:

```
df_id <- data.table::rbindlist(listOfDataFrames, idcol = TRUE)
```

The  `idcol` parameter adds a column (`.id`) identifying the origin of the dataframe contained in the list. The result would look to something like this:

```
.id a         b           c
1   u   -0.05315128 -1.31975849 
1   b   -1.00404849 1.15257952  
1   y   1.17478229  -0.91043925 
1   q   -1.65488899 0.05846295  
1   c   -1.43730524 0.95245909  
1   b   0.56434313  0.93813197
```

Answer (score 11):

An updated visual for those wanting to compare some of the recent answers (I wanted to compare the purrr to dplyr solution). Basically I combined answers from @TheVTM and @rmf.

[image]

Code:

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)

dflist <- vector(length=10,mode="list")
for(i in 1:100)
{
  dflist[[i]] <- data.frame(a=runif(n=260),b=runif(n=260),
                            c=rep(LETTERS,10),d=rep(LETTERS,10))
}


mb <- microbenchmark(
  dplyr::bind_rows(dflist),
  data.table::rbindlist(dflist),
  purrr::map_df(dflist, bind_rows),
  do.call("rbind",dflist),
  times=500)

ggplot2::autoplot(mb)
```

Session Info:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
```

Package Versions:

```
> packageVersion("tidyverse")
[1] ‘1.1.1’
> packageVersion("data.table")
[1] ‘1.10.0’
```

Answer (score 3):

A very fast option is the C-written `collapse::unlist2d`:

```r
library(collapse)
unlist2d(listOfDataFrames)
```

---

Since `purrr 1.0.0`, another option is `list_rbind` (which supersedes `flatten_dfr` and (partly) `map_dfr`):

```r
library(purrr)
list_rbind(listOfDataFrames, names_to = "column_label")
```

---

`unlist2d` is faster than any other option:

```r
library(microbenchmark)
mb <- microbenchmark(
  bind_rows = dplyr::bind_rows(listOfDataFrames),
  rbindlist = data.table::rbindlist(listOfDataFrames),
  do.call = do.call("rbind", listOfDataFrames),
  list_rbind = list_rbind(listOfDataFrames),
  unlist2d = unlist2d(listOfDataFrames), times = 1000)

# Unit: microseconds
#        expr       min         lq       mean     median         uq      max neval
#   bind_rows  1590.601  2139.7010  2807.0167  2335.2510  2717.3510  51773.4  1000
#   rbindlist   613.401   890.6015  1438.0510  1012.7505  1318.3015  13893.4  1000
#     do.call 12009.201 19973.7010 25526.6986 22102.8005 25239.9510 151914.2  1000
#  list_rbind  1287.401  1781.1510  2510.0104  1970.5515  2282.3515 115803.6  1000
#    unlist2d   245.401   400.3015   937.1731   488.3005   690.5015  12683.0  1000
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the best answer `data.table::rbindlist(x, fill=TRUE)` didn't work for me. Instead, it corrupted my data, which I found out only during analysis when some rows that had value before merging lost their value after merging.

Other solutions using `merge` or `rbind` also didn't work due to a differing number of columns.

So I had to develop my own special solution. Its two short functions with base! Nothing else required.

The first issue is that we can't subset `data.frame` with non-existing columns. But if we solve that, we can just subset those `data.frame`s and `rbind` the result.

```r
subset_missing = function(x, select){
    y = lapply(select, \(y) if(y %in% names(x)) x[[y]] else NA)
    data.frame(y) |> setNames(select)
    }
```

This is a cleaned solution from another StackOverflow answer.

Once we have that, the rest is easy!

```r
merge_df = function(x){
    nm = lapply(x, colnames) |> unlist() |> unique()
    y = lapply(x, subset_missing, select = nm)
    do.call(what = rbind, y)
    }
```

Now, lets test it:

```
df1 = data.frame(a = c(1:5), b = c(6:10))
df2 = data.frame(a = c(11:15), b = c(16:20), c = LETTERS[1:5])

merge_df(list(df1, df2))

#     a  b    c
# 1   1  6 <NA>
# 2   2  7 <NA>
# 3   3  8 <NA>
# 4   4  9 <NA>
# 5   5 10 <NA>
# 6  11 16    A
# 7  12 17    B
# 8  13 18    C
# 9  14 19    D
# 10 15 20    E
```

It will be definitely slower than many solutions here since it is solving slightly different problem, but it actually works for my issue, so I hope that other people will have luck with it.