# How convert a list of named vectors in to a data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

Here is how the list looks:

```
>>>print(pelist)
[[1]]
     Power Type I Error
[1,]     1     0.024339

[[2]]
     Power Type I Error
[1,]   0.8     0.038095

[[3]]
     Power Type I Error
[1,]     1     0.032804
```

I can do it this way, but it quickly becomes impractical as the size of the list grows:

```
>>>rbind(pelist[[1]], pelist[[2]], pelist[[3]])
     Power Type I Error
[1,]   1.0     0.024339
[2,]   0.8     0.038095
[3,]   1.0     0.032804
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851327/r-converting-a-list-of-data-frames-into-one-data-frame

Comment: Those list elements are actually matrices with column names.

Answer (score 3):

The idiomatic approach is to use `do.call`

```
do.call(rbind, pelist)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that your list elements have all the same length, you can also use

```
 test_list=list(matrix(c(1,2),ncol=2,nrow=1),matrix(c(3,4),ncol=2,nrow=1),matrix(c(5,6),ncol=2,nrow=1))

 test_matrix=matrix(unlist(test_list),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
```

I am not sure, but this is probably faster than subsequent rbind calls.

Comment: Both the OP and @mnel are doing a single call to `rbind`. And it being an .Internal function, you can bet it's not wasting resources.

Comment: BTW: You made me curious :) `library(rbenchmark);

test_list=list(matrix(c(1,2),ncol=2,nrow=1),matrix(c(3,4),ncol=2,nrow=1),matrix(c(5,6),ncol=2,nrow=1));

bind1=function(x) matrix(unlist(x),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE);
bind2=function(x) do.call(rbind,x);

benchmark(replications=800000,
          bind1(test_list),
          bind2(test_list),
          columns=c("test", "elapsed", "replications"))` Same performance ;)