# laply to access a single value

Tags: r, list, dataframe, plyr

I have a list of data.frames and would like to construct a new data.frame from the list like so:

```
 u=runif(2, 0, 1)
 u.obs=list(data.frame(site='dl',  
                       swe.obs=runif(4, 0, 1),
                       model.type='r'),
            data.frame(site='nt', 
                       swe.obs=runif(5, 0, 1),
                       model.type='lm'),
            data.frame(site='nt',
                       swe.obs=runif(3,0,1),
                       model.type='lm'),
            data.frame(site='nt',
                       swe.obs=runif(3,0,1),
                       model.type='r'))
```

EDIT: @dickoa gave an answer that worked for my example but not for real so I am adding to u.obs to make it more real.

EDIT2: Just kidding. it looked different, but is the same from what I can tell.

```
summ.df=data.frame(model=u,
                   obs.min=laply(u.obs$swe.obs, min), 
                   obs.max=laply(u.obs$swe.obs, max), 
                   obs.mean=laply(u.obs$swe.obs, mean),
                   site=laply(u.obs$site, '[', 1),
                   model.type=laply(u.obs$model.type, '[', 1), 
                   date=laply(u.obs$date, '[', 1))
```

but I can't extrct `site` and `model.type` even though `u.obs[[1]]$site[1]` works fine. Can someone assist me?
Thanks

Comment: take a look at     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851327/converting-a-list-of-data-frames-into-one-data-frame-in-r

Comment: i missed that one, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number 1: use spaces and carriage returns in your code.  It will help with debugging for you and for us!

Number 2: your question:

Look at the results of your first few `laply` calls:

```
laply(u.obs$swe.obs, min)
# logical(0)
```

This is because `u.obs$swe.obs` doesn't exist.  Instead you want `u.obs[[i]]$swe.obs`.  You can get there using an anonymous function, or the amazingly handy `summarise`.

```
laply(u.obs, summarise, min(swe.obs))
```

Now that your later assignments are not 0, you will get the result you expected.  However,
The excellent thing about `summarise` and `plyr`, is that you don't have to build the data.frame like that. Instead, use `ldply`

```
summ.df <- ldply(u.obs, 
                 summarise,
                 obs.min=min(swe.obs),
                 site=site[1])
```

Comment: awesome, thanks. It's incredible what R and people who know how to use it can do.  I swear I tried `laply(u.obs$swe,min)` itself but I must have changed my data structure or something. Thanks for your help. I had to follow it with `summ.df<-rbind(model=u,summ.df)` to get what I wanted.

Comment: oh, and thanks for the heads up on summarise! didn't know of that one.

Answer (score 1):

If your final data has the same structure it will be easier to change your approach by binding (row-wise) your data first.

Using your data

```
set.seed(1)
u <- runif(2, 0, 1)
u.obs <- list(
data.frame(site='dl',  
swe.obs=runif(4, 0, 1),
model.type='r'),
data.frame(site='nt', 
           swe.obs=runif(5, 0, 1),
           model.type='lm'))
```

We can something like this

```
require(plyr)
ddply(do.call(rbind, u.obs), .(site, model.type), summarise,
      obs.min = min(swe.obs), 
      obs.max = max(swe.obs), 
      obs.mean = mean(swe.obs))

##   site model.type  obs.min obs.max obs.mean
## 1   dl          r 0.201682 0.90821  0.64528
## 2   nt         lm 0.061786 0.94468  0.50047
```

Comment: fyi, from reading the link from @user2510479 it seems `rbind.fill()` might be a better choice to `do.call(rbind,list)`

Comment: This actually makes all my code shorter. I did a bunch of processing leading up to my question that can be eliminated if i just use `ddply(original.df,.(site,model.type),summarise,...)`. when will i learn.

Comment: @Dominik Glad to help.  While you're learning, take a look at `data.table`.  The syntax will be a little different at first, but it is amazingly fast once you've groked it.