# R - How to transform a list of all 1*2 matrix to a matrix

Tags: r, list, matrix, factory

I have a list, and its head is:

```
$AK
    hospital state
NA     <NA>  <NA>

$AL
                         hospital state
20 D W MCMILLAN MEMORIAL HOSPITAL    AL

$AR
                            hospital state
20 ARKANSAS METHODIST MEDICAL CENTER    AR

$AZ
                              hospital state
20 JOHN C LINCOLN DEER VALLEY HOSPITAL    AZ

$CA
                hospital state
20 SHERMAN OAKS HOSPITAL    CA

$CO
                    hospital state
20 SKY RIDGE MEDICAL CENTER    CO
```

I want to merge this list to a matrix, like this:

```
                              hospital state
AK                                <NA> AK
AL      D W MCMILLAN MEMORIAL HOSPITAL AL
AR   ARKANSAS METHODIST MEDICAL CENTER AR
AZ JOHN C LINCOLN DEER VALLEY HOSPITAL AZ
CA               SHERMAN OAKS HOSPITAL CA
CO            SKY RIDGE MEDICAL CENTER CO
```

notice: the first line of the matrix is different from the first item in the list. In the list, the state of the first item is `<NA>`, but the state of the first line in the matrix is AK. It is that merge the list's factor and the "hospital" in the list.
What should I do?

And what if I want to merge the items in the list into a matrix?

Comment: `do.call(rbind,mylist)`.

Comment: @the OP, don't change the question please.

Comment: Should I delete this question?

Comment: Duplicate of [Converting a list of data frames into one data frame in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851327/converting-a-list-of-data-frames-into-one-data-frame-in-r).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `rbind` the 'lst' elements by using `do.call`

```
do.call(rbind, lst)
```

Comment: Could you kindly remove your answer, as you marked it as duplicated?

Comment: Because by closing the question, only your answer remains. You don't allow other to post an answer.

Comment: @Pascal Look, you posted the dupe link and somebody else have already suggested it as a dupe before I duped it.

Comment: @Pascal Are you saying that when you comment with a dupe link, I shouldn't dupe it?  Come on, this is crazy!

Comment: I am saying that when you accept the dupe, you cannot keep your only answer. It is not fair.

Comment: @Pascal But, you can post an answer (if you were so concerned about my only answer).  Look, I didn't even think about this when I closed it.  I was only being a loyal, dutiful SO community member.

Comment: @Pascal That's up to me.  Also, it's kind of doing a disservice to the person who posted the question.  I answered it before you posted the link.

Comment: @Pascal If that is the case, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35717491/how-to-delete-dataframes-row-with-3-of-5-equal-element) is also a dupe.

Comment: Yes, also a dupe. The question is not regarding the OP. The question is once you posted an answer, don't accept the dupe ans freeze the question. If you do so, remove your answer.

Comment: Take it easy. It's my fault, I don't find the answer before. But I think we should not abuse our right of vote. The answer is right, and I am grateful for you both. By the way, should I delete this question?

Comment: @Vansiee You don't have to delete the question as no matter if it is a dupe or not, it will increase the chances of finding an answer to this kind of question when somebody search on the google.

Comment: @akrun Thank you very much! I think so. When I google my question, I didn't find the answer I want, so I asked. Maybe my google skill is not good. Hope my question will help others whose google skill is not good enough.

Comment: @Vansiee You are completely right.  I also find it very difficult to find dupes when using some keywords.

Comment: @Pascal Although my question is dup, I think the form of my question is helpful for the freshman whose google skill is not good enough. And akrun's answer is what I want, which maybe others want, and it will not cause bad result. I hope you can cancel your downvote. Thank you.

Comment: @Vansiee It's okay.  I don't care much about the votes.  My happiness comes from helping people.

Comment: @Pascal What's more, if there is only one form of one kind question, isn't it hard for everyone to get what they want? After all, there are a thousand Hamlets in a thousand people's eyes. So, I hope you could reconsider your downvote. Thank you.