# Bring each value in the list to its own column

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I have a dat frame called crimeLARaw_tbl_final.

One of the columns called location_1.coordinates, is a ‘list’ data type column which contains a list of values:

**location_1.coordinates**

```
c(-118.3157, 34.0454)

c(-118.2717, 34.001)

c(-118.2671, 34.0294)

c(-118.4517, 33.967)
```

How could I bring each value in the list to its own column?

```
 long           lat

-118.3157      34.0454

-118.2717      34.001

-118.2671      34.0294

-118.4517      33.967
```

I have tried with dplyr and stringr but not getting anywhere.

Thank you

Comment: `do.call(rbind, your_list)`

Comment: @Sotos Is there anyway of doing this with dplyr and stringr?

Comment: I added another [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851327/convert-a-list-of-data-frames-into-one-data-frame) to the dupe. It has a lot of ways of doing it including the `bind_rows` from `dplyr`