# no such file or directory (error in R)

Tags: r

I want to import and bind in one data frame a set of .csv files. 
I create a list of files and then a for loop to read each of the files and bind them together. However, at the second file I receive an error saying that such a file or directory is missing. However it is indeed present in the list of files I create. Any recommendations on the issue, please? Thank you.

```
file.names <- list.files(path = pathname, pattern = " trial.csv")

for(i in seq(file.names)){
  file1 <- read.csv(file.names[i], header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  file1 <- t(file)
  file1 <- data.frame(file, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  colnames(file1) = file1[1,]
  print(file1)
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should set your working directory to `pathname`? Or use `full.names = T` in `list.files`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `list.files()` returns file names without the directory details. When importing files you typically want to set `full.names = TRUE` to return absolute paths (including directory names).

A good code pattern is as follows.

```
library(assertive.files)
files_to_import <- list.files(some_path, full.names = TRUE)
assert_all_are_existing_files(files_to_import)
data <- lapply(files_to_import, read.csv)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to import **and bind in one data frame** a set of .csv files.

@richie-cotton provided an answer that fixed your path issue, but I want to address the highlighted part of your question.

Richie Cotton's code:

```
library(assertive.files)
files_to_import <- list.files(some_path, full.names = TRUE)
assert_all_are_existing_files(files_to_import)
data <- lapply(files_to_import, read.csv)
```

Will end in `data`, a list of data.frames. You want these to be one `data.frame`. Take a look at this answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18489830/5333994

My suggestion would be to end with using `rbindlist` on the resulting list of `data.frame`.

```
library(data.table)
data <- rbindlist(data)
```

In fact, if you're going to use `data.table` you can replace `read.csv` with `fread` which will likely speed things up.

```
library(data.table)
library(assertive.files)
files_to_import <- list.files(some_path, full.names = TRUE)
assert_all_are_existing_files(files_to_import)
data <- rbindlist(lapply(files_to_import, fread))
```

If you want to end in a `data.frame` rather than `data.table` simply use `setDF`.

```
setDF(data)
```

If you want to avoid `data.table` all together, running `do.call` is probably your best option.

```
data <- do.call("rbind", data)
```

Note from the answer I linked above that this is likely to be a much slower operation than using `rbindlist`, depending on the number of files you have.