# merge list of dataframes into one dataframe with id

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

I have a dataframe with ids of participants as a first, and and their responses as json array as a second column.
So it is basically a data frame with 240 observations: 240 participant codes, and 240 arrays with 13 responses in each observation that can be converted into a 3X10 array each
 Looking like something like that:

[image]

I convert  json into a dataframe using `jsonlite::fromJSON`, and as a result I get a list of data.frames (shortened up for the simplicity):

```
[[1]]
   case_n  d1  d2
1      13   0 100
2      12 100   0
3      11   0 100

[[2]]
   case_n  d1  d2
1      12  50  50
2       8  50  50
3       3  50  50


[[3]]
   case_n d1 d2
1      11 50 50
2       7 50 50
3      13 50 50
```

I know that these can be merged into one large dataframe containing all dataframes for example using plyr::ldply

```
df <- ldply(converted_json, data.frame)
```

**What is the way to correctly merge this extended `df` with initial `participant.code`?**

So the wanted result would be something like;

```
partcode   case_n d1 d2
8pdpaqyv      11 50 50
8pdpaqyv       7 50 50
8pdpaqyv      13 50 50
3q8o3mry      11 50 50
3q8o3mry       7 50 50
3q8o3mry      13 50 50
1kueczzz      11 50 50
1kueczzz       7 50 50
1kueczzz      13 50 50
```

UPDATE: the task is a bit different from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851327/convert-a-list-of-data-frames-into-one-data-frame), because I also need to store the ids from the initial data.

Comment: Where is the `100` in the expected output

Comment: @A.Suliman: just added an explanation why it's not a pure duplicate

Comment: @PhilippChapkovski Two of the answers of that question explain how to add these ids.

Comment: @A.Suliman: It is not in the body, but rather in comments to some answers, but ok, you are right. I can delete this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dplyr::bind_rows` should do what you want (it binds list elements). You have to pass additional argument for `.id`. To make this `.id` you have to name list elements.

```
# Name list elements
names(converted_json) <- dataOriginal$participant.code
# bind rows and add .id
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(converted_json, .id = "partcode")
```

Comment: Please, don't post answers to questions that were asked hundreds of times, mark it as a duplicate. This way you will help OP to find more answers and rich discussion.