# Converting a list to CSV in R

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

I have recently plunged into R on a totally self-taught basis (may not have
been the smartest decision!)

I am attempting to download tickers as a time series.  I can successfully
create RDA files but I want to convert them to CVS.  Following is the code I
have created so far.

```
if (!require(BatchGetSymbols)) install.packages('BatchGetSymbols')
library(BatchGetSymbols)

tickers <- c('SPY','VCR', 'RPG')
first.date <- Sys.Date() - 365
last.date <- Sys.Date
l.out <- BatchGetSymbols(tickers = tickers, 
                         first.date = first.date,
                         last.date = last.date,
                         cache.folder = file.path("c://Users/Owner/Documents/R",
                                                  'BGS_Cache') )

print(l.out$df.control)
print(l.out$df.tickers)
```

I can `print(l.out)` and see that it contains all the data, but it is not a
data.frame

Can anyone help with creating a data.frame and then converting to CSV?

Comment: Can you copy and paste the output of `dput(head(l.out))` into your question please? Having a sample of the data helps clarify what the problem is.

Comment: `as.data.frame` will convert an object into a data.frame and `write.table` with the appropriate arguments will write an object as a `.csv` file. If you can't figure it out from that, post `dput(l.out)` and `str(l.out)`

Comment: If `l.out` is a list (which maybe it is from the title) then these questions will have your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227223/r-list-to-data-frame?rq=1 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851327/convert-a-list-of-data-frames-into-one-data-frame?rq=1

Comment: the as.data.frame and write.table are successful.  Thank you for your response?