# Why aren't my absolute references being saved in the foreach loop?

Tags: r

So if I have an array, and I want to input a value in each index via a loop, using *for* (as demonstrated below) works, but in the equivalent of *foreach* (again, below) the array's values aren't saved. Does anyone know why?

```
z<-rep(NA,n)
test_func<-function(){
  z[i+1]<<-i+1
}

for ( i in 1:n){
  test_func()
}
head(z)
```

All good.

```
z<-rep(NA,n)
foreach (i = 1:n, .packages=c("mvtnorm")) %dopar% {
  test_func()
}
head(z)
```

In this second case, z is still filled with NAs.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `test_func` returns `NULL` the assignment to `z` in the global environment is a side effect (and I would argue bad practice). In your `%dopar%` loop, `z` does not exist in the global environment of each worker process.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess I need to learn more about %dopar%, because I am unware of needing to create the variable for each process. I created z before even starting the loop, so I assumed it'd exist everywhere.

Comment: The problem isn't in understanding %dopar% its in the general application of functions and loops. You should return values from function not assign to a different environment from within them (which is what `<<-` compared with `<-` does as Limey said). Also, you aren't even parsing `i` as an argument to the function and if you are using `i+1` in both the assignment and calculation why not just use `i`?

Comment: @LifeisGood94 Yes, it *does* exist everywhere because it gets copied from the main process into the worker processes when those start (Limey’s comment isn’t quite correct) but changes to it are only visible to the worker process, not to the main process (because memory isn’t copied *back* when the worker processes finish). As you said, this is a feature of `%dopar%` that you need to study. In general, relying on side effects in R is a bad idea (with a few, carefully selected, exceptions).

Comment: When I run your code with {foreach} v. 1.5.2 I get the error `"object 'i' not found"`. When I do pass `i` as an argument to `test_func()` then `%dopar%` works in the same way as the regular `for` loop.

Comment: Hmmm...this all makes sense to me. Thank you all. @Sarah I was just doing a demonstration. This isn't the true function I'm making, but same rules apply.

Comment: @TimTeaFan Did you register a parallel cluster? Because the default behaviour of `%dopar%` is *not* to perform parallel but rather sequential execution. In that case (but *only* in that case) it will work.

Comment: @KonradRudolph yes correct, I did not register a parallel cluster. I just used to code from the OP. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Consider

```
n <- 5
test_func1 <- function(x){
  x+1
}

z <- lapply(1:n, test_func1)
z
[[1]]
[1] 2

[[2]]
[1] 3

[[3]]
[1] 4

[[4]]
[1] 5

[[5]]
[1] 6
```

[If you want `z` to be a vector rather than a list, then replace `lapply` with `sapply`.]

This has the same effect as your non-parallel code, but I claim it is better because

- `test_func1` is self-contained.  It does not depend on the previous creation of `z` in the global environment for its correct operation
- a common feature of good programming practice is that functions should be self-contained.  Here, `test_func` is not because of the use of `<<-`.  Calling `test_func`may unwittingly modify `z` in their global environment, potentially causing downsteam errors that are difficult to diagnose.  See for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54064394/when-is-rs-assign-function-appropriate).  `assign` and `<<-` are (almost) equivalent.
- it makes the modification/creation of `z` explicit: the casual observer does not need to know the internals of `test_func1` to know that calling it modifies `z` in the global environment
- it is more generic.  It can be applied to any variable, not just `z`
- Once `test_func1` is defined, it is more compact

Now write

```
# Please include all referenced packages in future so that your code is reproducible
library(foreach)

z <- foreach (i = 1:n) %dopar% {
  test_func1(i)
}
z
[[1]]
[1] 2

[[2]]
[1] 3

[[3]]
[1] 4

[[4]]
[1] 5

[[5]]
[1] 6
```

Another advantage: parallelisation works. :=)

As I explained in my comment, this is because the modified function does not depend on the prior existence of `z` (in the global environment of each worker thread) for correct operation.

With regard to your comment "I assumed it'd exist everywhere": it depends on what you mean by "everywhere".  `z` exists in the global environment of your current/parent process.  It does not exist everywhere else.  Specifically, it doesn't exist in worker process spawned by the current process, just as it wouldn't (necessarily) exist in a new R session that you start on the same machine tomorrow, or another R session that you start on a different machine today.

Comment: “Specifically, it doesn't exist in worker process” — That isn’t correct, it *does* exist (at least when using a fork or socket cluster — check by running `exists('z')` inside the parallel loop). But modifications are confined to the worker threads, they’re not copied back to the parent process (and that wouldn’t work anyway because it would create conflicts/races).

Comment: I don't know if you're asking me or @KonradRudolph.  I'm not recommending either method.  You know your real use case better than I do.  What I wanted to show you was how to get your parallelisation working correctly.  And to explain why the changes weren't just to make your code work, but to improve it more generally.  Note Konrad's correction to one of my claims.

Comment: Thank you. I'm a bit confused here. Are you advocating for the apply? Because the second method you show is an edit of mine.

Comment: @Limey gotcha. Thank you :) Yes I think I'm going to go with mine b/c of the easy parallelization.