# Is there a way to get dataframe rows based on a vector of row indexes?

Tags: r

I have a vector 'a' that is a numerical vector of row indices. I'd like to get these rows as well as the next 20 rows next to them out of a dataframe called 'data'. Is there a way to do this?

I've already tried:
`data2 <- data[a:a+20,]` but without success.

If `a <- c(1, 21, 42)`
I'd like to extract rows 1:20, 21:41, and 42:62 from 'data' and store them in another object.

Comment: `data2 <- data[-a,]` ? Your question isn't very clear. What do you expect the final dataframe to look like? Are you trying to get a single dataframe or a list of three dataframes? An actual example (perhaps using a built-in dataset like `trees`) would help.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I want actually a single dataframe rowbind of 1:20, 21:41, 31:41 (but with values specified by values in the vector a). The end result is basically a subset of the original dataframe.

Comment: How do you get from `c(1,21,31)` to `1:20, 21:41, 31:41`? For one thing, where did `41` come from? Furthermore, wouldn't `1:20, 21:41, 31:41` duplicate the rows in `31:41`, making the resulting dataframe no longer a subset?

Comment: I edited my question to fix that, my mistake. What I mean was, I have a vector of single numeric values (these values represent rows in a dataframe, ex. 1 represents row 1, 21 represents row 21 etc.) I want to take this vector, add 20 to the values, and extract ALL those rows from the dataset. Hope this was clearer. Thanks!

Comment: Why not ```data[1:62, ]```? Or if you have a vector, ```data[min(a):max(a), ]```.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is another way from base without fancy functions and for loops:

```
data2 <- data[rep(a, each = 21) + 0:20,]
```

Comment: IMHO this is absolutely preferable to doing *apply statements.

Comment: The point of this question now appears to be to show people, what is the effect of learning complicated things on the way they do simple things.

Comment: I agree that this answer is preferable and hope that OP accepts it instead.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you, the following should work:

```
do.call("rbind",lapply(a,function(i) data[i:(i+20),]))
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2851327/4996248) about how to convert a list of dataframes to a singe dataframe (which is the least intuitive part of my answer). The answers to that question give ways more intuitive than `do.call()`, but require going beyond base R.

Comment: @bactro This was the first thing that I thought of, but I think that the solution of Grada Gukovic is superior. Consider accepting their answer rather than mine.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way using `Map` from base R -

```
data[unlist(Map(`:`, a, a+20)), ]
```

Or with `sapply` (similar to John's answer) -

```
data[c(sapply(a, function(x) x:(x+20))), ]
```