# How to merge 3 different columns from 3 different tables into a large column. R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have three columns with the same data type.

data1$a

```
a
123
123
311
```

data2$a

```
a
231
461
456
```

data3$a

```
a
161
161
169
```

My desired goal is this.

newdataframe

```
a
123
123
311
123
123
311
161
161
169
```

Comment: Try `df <- data.frame(a=c(data1$a,data2$a,data3$a))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a list of data frames into one data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851327/convert-a-list-of-data-frames-into-one-data-frame)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably there is a better way to do it but to big problems simple solutions haha.

```
lst <- list(data1$a, data2$a, data3$a) #Create a list with your data

df <- data.frame(unlist(lst)) #Unlist all the lists created and create a data frame.
```

Or just like @Duck said:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(data1$a,data2$a,data3$a))
```

Answer (score 1):

If the rest of your dataframe also contain the same columns as the first one you can try

```
new_df <- rbind(data1, data2, data3)
```

to merge them together.

Answer (score 0):

We can load the data into a `list` and `unlist`

```
data.frame(a = unlist(mget(ls(pattern = '^data\\d+$'))))
```