# rbinding a list of lists of dataframes based on nested order

Tags: r, list, dataframe, plyr

I have a dataframe, `df` and a function `process` that returns a list of two dataframes, `a` and `b`. I use dlply to split up the `df` on an id column, and then return a list of lists of dataframes. Here's sample data/code that approximates the actual data and methods:

```
df <- data.frame(id1=rep(c(1,2,3,4), each=2))

process <- function(df) {
  a <- data.frame(d1=rnorm(1), d2=rnorm(1))
  b <- data.frame(id1=df$id1, a=rnorm(nrow(df)), b=runif(nrow(df)))
  list(a=a, b=b)
}

require(plyr)
output <- dlply(df, .(id1), process)
```

`output` is a list of lists of dataframes, the nested list will always have two dataframes, named `a` and `b`. In this case the outer list has a length 4.

What I am looking to generate is a dataframe with all the `a` dataframes, along with an `id` column indicating their respective value (I believe this is left in the list as the `split_labels` attribute, see str(output)). Then similarly for the `b` dataframes.

So far I have in part used this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652522/rbind-dataframes-in-a-list-of-lists) to come up with this code:

```
list <- unlist(output, recursive = FALSE)
list.a <- lapply(1:4, function(x) {
  list[[(2*x)-1]]
})
all.a <- rbind.fill(list.a)
```

Which gives me the final `a` dataframe (and likewise for `b` with a different subscript into `list`), however it doesn't have the id column I need and I'm pretty sure there's got to be a more straightforward or elegant solution. Ideally something clean using `plyr`.

Comment: I don't understand what it means that `all.a` "doesn't have the id column I need".  If the id column you need is the same `id1` as what's in `output[[i]]$b`, can't you just add that to your `process` function?

Answer (score 1):

Not very clean but you can try something like this (assuming the same data generation process).

```
list.aID <- lapply(1:4, function(x) {
cbind(list[[(2*x) - 1]], list[[2*x]][1, 1, drop = FALSE])
})

all.aID <- rbind.fill(list.aID)
all.aID

all.aID
        d1       d2 id1
1  0.68103 -0.74023   1
2 -0.50684  1.23713   2
3  0.33795 -0.37277   3
4  0.37827  0.56892   4
```